# Algorithm to find the minimum number of Granite Tiles to use

Tags: java, algorithm

1. I have N Granite Tiles with size H x W (Same image)

[image]

2. I have M piece of Granite Tiles , each piece has K element with size H1 X W1 (Same image)

[image]

I want to find the minimum number of Granite Tiles (W x H) to use to cover all M piece of Granite Tiles

Example input

[image]

[image]

What is Algorithm will be used for it?

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is a "bin packing" problem and has no known direct solution. It's an NP problem, meaning nondeterministic (N), but a solution can be checked in polynomial (P) time. A nondeterministic solution basically means try every combination, and stop when you find one that works.

Comment: To be more precise : this is a two dimensionnal bin packing. It does had exact solutions, but they are not fast. You will also find faster solutions, but they are not exact. See this : https://link.springer.com/article/10.1057/jors.1987.70